# How to get multi values from a single parameter into procedure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

Please help me with the following problem.

I want to get multi values from a single parameter into the procedure in SQL Server, I'm learning SQL and C#.

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE AProc_Getback 
    (@fcode VARCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t_PALM_PersonnelFileMst 
    SET fdflag = 0, frdate = null, fddate = null,
        fdtype = null, fdreason = null
    WHERE fcode IN ('@fcode')

    DELETE FROM t_pald_dimissiontrm 
    WHERE fcode IN ('@fcode')
END

Exec AProc_Getback '512888,512889'
```

Thanks very much

Comment: I've edited the question and in addition to formatting, changed your input value from '512888'512889' to '512888,512889'. i.e. comma separated value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine)

```sql
CREATE TYPE FCodes AS TABLE ( 
    Code VARCHAR(32) -- Use type of "fcode" column
);
```

Stored procedure

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE AProc_Getback 
(
    @fcode FCodes
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t_PALM_PersonnelFileMst SET
        fdflag = 0,
        frdate = null,
        fddate = null,
        fdtype = null, 
        fdreason = null
    WHERE fcode IN (SELECT Code FROM @fcode)

    DELETE FROM t_pald_dimissiontrm 
    WHERE fcode IN (SELECT Code FROM @fcode)
END
```

Execute

```sql
DECLARE @Codes AS FCodes
INSERT INTO @Codes VALUES ('123'), ('456'), ('789')

EXEC AProc_Getback @Codes
```

From C# you can create parameter of type `SqlDbType.Structure` with `DataTable` as value and pass it to the stored procedures

```
var codesParameter = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@fcodes",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structure,
    TypeName = "dbo.FCodes", // Important! - name of type in database
    Value = dataTableOfCodes // Should contain column with name "Code"
};

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) 
{
    command.CommandText = "dbo.AProc_Getback";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(codesParameter);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: parameter of procedure is @fcode FCodes, I don't understand.

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn, `FCodes` is type of the parameter `@fcode`. You will create this type by executing first script `CREATE TYPE FCodes AS TABLE...`

Comment: upvoted for a comprehensive and detailed answer. Bravo Fabio

Comment: Dear Fabio, I created web form on asp.net, and when i input value in textbox, if that value not exit in t_PALM_PersonnelFileMst table, it will show a error for user, how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your parameter must be capable of holding incoming data. currently, it can only receive data up to 10 characters. See `@fcode varchar(10)`.

If you don't have split function available with you, you can create one. Alternatively, you can use some inline code to achieve that. For example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE AProc_Getback(@Fcode VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #FCodes (Item  VARCHAR(30));
    DECLARE @Insert VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO #FCodes VALUES ('''+REPLACE(@Fcode,',','''),(''')+''');';
    EXEC (@Insert);   


    UPDATE t_PALM_PersonnelFileMst
    SET
        fdflag = 0,
        frdate = NULL,
        fddate = NULL,
        fdtype = NULL,
        fdreason = NULL
    WHERE fcode IN(SELECT Item FROM #FCodes);


    DELETE FROM t_pald_dimissiontrm
    WHERE fcode IN(SELECT Item FROM #FCodes);
END;
```

Comment: Dear Mr,Thank you very much, let me try

Comment: dear!, how to exec this procedure ? i exec with EXEC AProc_Getback '000009','000010', so it say "Procedure or function AProc_Getback has too many arguments specified."

Comment: just use as  '000009,000010' or if you have more values, use  '000009,000010,000009,000010'. that means only one pair of ' ' around all values and comma (,) between all values. gave examples below:

Comment: Exec AProc_Getback '512888,512889'

Comment: Exec AProc_Getback '512888,512889,5128890'

Comment: Happy to help dear :-)

Comment: What if I do `EXEC AProc_Getback "');DROP TABLE t_PALM_PersonnelFileMst; --"`? ;)

Comment: To me, that is a call with bad parameter values. What are your wise and educated thoughts on that?

Comment: Dear, I created web form on asp.net, and when i input value in textbox, if that value not exit in t_PALM_PersonnelFileMst table, it will show a error for user, how can i do?

Comment: I guess your question is for the Fabio, as his answer is correct and you are using his solution? Besides, asp.net is not my domain of expertise...

Comment: Thank you,Viking.

Comment: Good luck my friend:-)

Comment: Hi Viking, can you show me how to get Messages from Sql server on c# when i click button?

Comment: Sorry dear. only SQL is my thing. Apologies.

Comment: Hi Viking,  how to set @outitem = multi values to print it out side messages,thank's

Comment: In dataset, choose parameters, then on left side box, write `@OutItem` and on right side box, select Expression and write `=JOIN(Parameters!Whatever.Value,",")`

Comment: I don't understand...i have this line Select @outitem = Item From #ItemNotOKtable2 and I printed it ok on Print '@outitem'; but it only print one value, i want to print it with multi values, how i do ?Thank Viking

Comment: your questions stop making sense dear. May be you need to ask separate question to seek the solution and paste all details and images. you are totally going off topic.

Comment: thank Viking, I only know this website someone days, so someone i understand,I hope your help, I see you are a good man, if you don't feel uncomfortable we are make friend, do you have skype or facebook? my skype is minhthanh114

Answer (score -1):

```
  Alter PROCEDURE AProc_Getback ( @fcode varchar(Max)

    ) AS

    Begin update t_PALM_PersonnelFileMst set fdflag = 0,frdate = null,fddate = null,fdtype = null, fdreason = null where fcode in (select Item
from dbo.SplitString(@fcode, ',')) 
    delete from t_pald_dimissiontrm where fcode in (select Item
from dbo.SplitString(@fcode, ',')) end
```

then

```
Exec AProc_Getback '512888,512889'
```

Comment: Dear Hiran nuwanga, I created web form on asp.net, and when i input value in textbox, if that value not exit in t_PALM_PersonnelFileMst table, it will show a error for user, how can i do?